# no result while inserting data in database?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have this form:

```
<form action="index.php?type=add_lesson&type=add" method="post">
                <?php echo $lesson_title; ?><br/><input type="text" name="title" style="width:450px;" /><br/>
                <?php echo $lesson_url; ?><br/><input type="text" name="url" style="width:450px;" /><br/>
                <?php echo $keywords; ?><br/><input type="text" name="kewyords" style="width:450px;" />
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $submit;?>" class="button"  /></form>
```

and this index.php code:

```
if($_GET['type'] == "add_lesson"){
        include_once(fls."add_lesson.php");
    }
```

and this add_lesson.php code:

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'add'){
    $title    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $url      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['url']);
    $kewyords = htmlspecialchars($_POST['kewyords']);
        $sql = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO LESSONS(L_TITLE,L_URL,L_COMMENTS,L_VIEWS,L_KEYWORDS)
                                VALUES('".$title."','".$url."','0','0','".$kewords."') ");
        echo $added_sucessfully;
}
```

but when I click submit I get white page
what is the problem??

Comment: you have used $mysqli->query? are you sure you are connecting to database?

Comment: @user2008945 --> yes, I am sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your code: include_once(fls."add_lesson.php"); probably you ment include_once($fls."add_lesson.php");

Also make sure your php installation shows php errors. Probably you have Fatal PHP Error that is not displaying.

Here is simple tutorial to follow to make sure you see php errors:
http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-display-php-errors-in-my-script-code-when-display-errors-is-disabled-t453.html

Another thing.. You have

`<form action="index.php?type=add_lesson&type=add" method="post">`

So you get only type=add in PHP :)

Comment: what is the error in `include_once(fls."add_lesson.php");` and sure about php installation shows php errors

Comment: Check I updated my answer, you depend having `type=add_lesson` in your PHP code, but it will never have this value because you are passing type=add afterwards replacing add_lesson :)

`index.php?type=add_lesson&type=add"`
is equivalent to 
`index.php?type=add"`

Comment: I created now `if($_GET['type']=='add'){//sql code here}` in index.php and I get succes result but how to make it in `index.php?type=add_lesson&type=add` ??

Comment: Try changing it to `index.php?action=add_lesson&type=add` Then you will have `if($_GET['action'] == "add_lesson")` & then `if($_GET['type'] == 'add')`